# How to initialise interface properties in complex interfaces

Tags: typescript

I want to initialise the properties in a function.  I am having the following error.  What is wrong with my code?

> Type '{ ErrorMessage: string; Label: string; Name: string; Text: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IUserProps'.
>     Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'ErrorMessage' does not exist in type 'IUserProps'.

```
export interface IField {
    Label: string,
    Name: string,
    ErrorMessage: string,
    Text: string
  }

  export interface IUserProps {
      FirstName: IField,
      Email:IField   
     }

    interface IUserState {
    user:{
        Email:IUserProps,
        FirstName: IUserProps 
    }  
}
const setDefaultUserState :() =>IUserState= () =>({

        Email: {
            ErrorMessage: '',
            Label:'Email',
            Name:'Email',            
            Text: ''
        },       
        FirstName: {
            ErrorMessage: '',
            Label:'Email',
            Name:'Email',            
            Text: ''
        },       

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- According to your typse `IUserState` has a property `user` that has those properties. You omitted that.
- Also `IUserProps` and `IUserState` are identical but you nest them which does not make logical sense. I removed `IUserProps`.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-thjmwp)

```
export interface IField {
    Label: string,
    Name: string,
    ErrorMessage: string,
    Text: string
}


export interface IUserState {
    user:{
        Email:IField,
        FirstName: IField 
    }  
}


export var setDefaultUserState:() => IUserState = () => ({
  user: {
    Email: {
      ErrorMessage: '',
      Label:'Email',
      Name:'Email',            
      Text: ''
    },       
    FirstName: {
      ErrorMessage: '',
      Label:'Email',
      Name:'Email',            
      Text: ''
    },
  }}
)
```